# retweet functionality rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When can I find a gem for add "**retweet functionality**" to my project in ruby on rails 3.1.

e.j. **If I have a post and I want the feature, that other people repost my post in his model**

Add a example for a user can clone/copy or repost a user's post:

**User 1** have this post:

```
original = Post.last
 => #<Post _id: 4f2ad6bd1d41c833850000d6, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-02-02 18:32:29 UTC, posted_filename: "240379698830561159_tgw0Xeom_c.png", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f2a64511d41c85ae0000002'), board_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f2ab49f1d41c86c2f0000ac'), category_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f1d4dfe1d41c86204000079'), content: "mi ducha">
```

The **User 2** want repost original post and he want catch some attributes and add own attributes. e.j.:

attributes to be captured:

```
attribs = post.attributes.select {|a| %w(created_at post_filename category_id content).include? a }
post_cloned = Post.new attribs
```

The **User 2** want add his own attributes **board_id** and **user_id** and want can update **content** attribute.

**How can the User 2 do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait for gem. Well, I found an article which is telling how to do it using javascript:

To implement the Retweet button in your application you need to follow the below steps.

**Step 1**

Add this javascript function within the body of your rails rhtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  tweetmeme_style = "compact"; 
  tweetmeme_url = 'http:'; 
  tweetmeme_source = 'your_mail_id'; 
</script>
```

**Step 2**

Finally add the Tweet button where ever you require in your rails application:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tweetmeme.com/i/scripts/button.js"></script>
```

Its acts same as Flike,but a single user can Tweet many times.It means the user can likes the page or the article many times.the count will increment Respectively. 
The article will post in your Twitter Account.

Thats it...you will get the Retweet button in your Rails Application. 
Hope it helps..

Cheers!

Comment: I don't search retweet in twitter. I'm search the functionality retweet for our aplications. I will go edit the question with a example more illustrative.

Comment: Ah,Okie.. humm.. hard luck, ...its easy but, you have to write your own logics and model for that :(

Comment: I have added a demo example @ror_master. Thank you very much!